# не могу запустить Faker в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Использую  Faker впервые. Выдает такую ошибку в tinkere.
Psy Shell v0.9.12 (PHP 7.3.2 — cli) by Justin Hileman

> > > factory(App\Role::class)->create();
> > >       PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:/OSPanel/domains/Oshsu/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Base.php on line 19
> > >       5

Миграция:

```html
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('i18n');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

RoleFactory:

```html
$factory->define(Role::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'i18n' => $faker->randomElement('ru','en','kg'),
    ];
});
```

Модель:

```html
class Role extends Model
{
    //
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Очень сомнительная строка:

`'i18n' => $faker->randomElement('ru','en','kg'),`

`randomElement` - должен быть массивом `randomElement(['ru','en','kg'])`

в [документации](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) про это ясно написано:

```
// returns randomly ordered subsequence of a provided array
randomElements($array = array ('a','b','c'), $count = 1) // array('c')
randomElement($array = array ('a','b','c')) // 'b'
```

Comment: Так и сделал. Все равно та же  ошибка.

Comment: Тогда приведите код который в вашем Seeder`e

Comment: Спасибо большое всем кто пытался помочь. Помогли )